# Padding Text view on center of linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a Back button on the top of my layout and i have placed the label text after that button. i need to center the label text, so that it should resemble like layout heading.Can anyone guide me on this task.

Comment: what layout you are using Linear or Relative ?

Comment: please see my answer for linear layout. You also ask for linear layout

Comment: have u tried any answers

Answer (score 1):

**Edited Code as per your response**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rlt1"
android:orientation="horizontal"   
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#24a6c6">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back_btn_img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Attractions"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need to make view compatible without mentioning numeric value. [link](http://pbrd.co/JMql0O)..i tryed.

Comment: @user2940599 so you will need this type of layout? right? using linear or relative ? please confirm quickly.

Comment: @user2940599 Please see my edited code. I have changed this code as per your given link.

Answer (score 1):

Hope u r looking for this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#0fa2da" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Text View"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/white_bar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#148cba"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Attractions"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In RelativeLayout try to set your `TextView` as `android:center_horizontal="true"`

Comment: He asked " Padding Text view on center of linear layout" . for LinearLayout dude, not for RelativeLayout.